# Error while calling function

Tags: c++, linux

I am getting an error when I call one static function of a class in to any other function (means by non-class function), then it is giving following error:

```
undefined reference to function name_function.
```

Can any one tell me why this is happing?

Comment: Could you please post some example code?

Comment: post your complete code and the error you get

Comment: Unless you post the relevant code, this question is likely to be closed. I've edited your question to improve its over-all quality, kindly proof read your questions prior to posting in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Basic C++: A non-static member function assumes that it has access to an object of the class type (it can refer to the member variables directly and the "this" pointer points to the object).

This means that you can't call a non-static member function unless you have an object of that type. In a static member function, you don't.

(I'm not 100% sure this is an answer to your question, as it's not clean from your explanation if you tried to call a non-static function from a static one, or vise versa.)

Comment: @user623133
  thanks 4 responce but  i am calling static functin from non-class member function. got it..

Comment: @balaji: if this solved your problem, mark the answer as *accepted*, by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you prepending the class name before the function name?

so, if you have:

```
class MyClass
{
    ...
    public static function name_function() { ... }
    ...
}
```

you need to call this function like this:

```
MyClass::name_function();
```

Comment: write i have to call this function as luke u said in different function which is non class function

Comment: ooops sorry I don't know why, but I thought you were talking about php, instead of C++. I don't know C++ sorry